# array record (json) from MySQL to html table

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to get data from MySQL with ajax and here is my code

```
function Testing()
{
    var text;
    var langData=[];
    
    
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'http://localhost/Android/Project/Edu/api/language/read.php',
    
    success:function (data) {
        
        langData = JSON.stringify(data);
        
        
        for (var i in langData) 
        {
           console.log("row " + i);
           for (var j in langData[i]) 
             {
                 text = text + " " + langData[i][j];
             }
        }
        
        document.getElementById('LanguageCode').value=text;
    },

    error: function () {
        alert('Failed');
    }
    
    });
}
```

and i got the result as the following

```
undefined {
    " r e c o r d s ": [{
        " L a n g u a g e I D ": " 1 ",
        " L a n g u a g e N a m e ": " E n g l i s h ",
        " L a n g u a g e C o d e ": " E n g ",
        " P r i o r i t y ": " 1 ",
        " R e g D a t e ": " 2 0 2 0 - 0 7 - 2 9 ",
        " S t a t u s ": " A c t i v e "
    }, {
        " L a n g u a g e I D ": " 2 ",
        " L a n g u a g e N a m e ": " C h i n e s e ",
        " L a n g u a g e C o d e ": " c n ",
        " P r i o r i t y ": " 0 ",
        " R e g D a t e ": " 2 0 2 0 - 0 8 - 0 1 ",
        " S t a t u s ": " A c t i v e "
    }, {
        " L a n g u a g e I D ": " 3 ",
        " L a n g u a g e N a m e ": " J a p a n e s e ",
        " L a n g u a g e C o d e ": " j p ",
        " P r i o r i t y ": " 0 ",
        " R e g D a t e ": " 2 0 2 0 - 0 8 - 0 1 ",
        " S t a t u s ": " A c t i v e "
    }]
}
```

all words / columns name got spacing and i want to create html table using that return data.

how do i Fix it?

Comment: give value for `text="";` before ajaxcall or before 1st for loop.... then you won't receive as undefined

Comment: I am not even sure why you are using `JSON.stringify(data);` in your data and your expected `dataType` as `json` in `ajax`

Comment: Why are you using JSON.stringify, `langData = JSON.stringify(data);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.. with your ajax json response...

```js
function Testing()
{
    var text='';
    var langData={"records":[{"LanguageID":"1","LanguageName":"English","LanguageCode":"Eng","Priority":"1","RegDate":"2020-07-29","Status":"Active"},{"LanguageID":"2","LanguageName":"Chinese","LanguageCode":"cn","Priority":"0","RegDate":"2020-08-01","Status":"Active"},{"LanguageID":"3","LanguageName":"Japanese","LanguageCode":"jp","Priority":"0","RegDate":"2020-08-01","Status":"Active"}]};
        for (var i in langData.records) {
                 text = text +'<tr><td>'+langData.records[i].LanguageID+'</td><td>'+langData.records[i].LanguageName+'</td><td>'+langData.records[i].LanguageCode+'</td><td>'+langData.records[i].Priority+'</td><td>'+langData.records[i].RegDate+'</td><td>'+langData.records[i].Status+'</td></tr>';
        }        document.getElementById('LanguageCode').innerHTML=text;
}
Testing();
```

```html
<table>
<thead><tr><th>LanguageID</th><th>LanguageName</th><th>LanguageCode</th><th>Priority</th><th>RegDate</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead>
<tbody id="LanguageCode"></tbody>
</table>
```